# I want to specific event to be colored differently

Tags: fullcalendar

When I input a Calendar event, I set type like public and personal. 
And, when I get it, I want personal event to be colored yellow.

I successfully input it and while coloring there is a problem and I get the following error message:

```
url : callCalendar is that Home Controller's method for get all Schedule List.
```

I do not know where to start.

Here is my code so far:

```
 displayEventTime: true,
        eventLimit : true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        events: function( start, end, timezone, callback ) { 
            alert("entering events function");
            var event = new Array();
            $.ajax({

                url : 'callCalendar',
                data : {
                    String : 'ss'
                },
                success : function(response){
                     for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                          event.push({
                              title : response[i].title,
                              start : response[i].start_date,
                          })
                          if(response[i].type=='personal'){
                              alert("Type = personal");
                              color: 'yellow'
                          }
                          color: 'yellow'
                      }
                     color: 'yellow'
                      callback(event);
                }
            });
            color: 'yellow'

        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'type' attribute to your events and try to use eventRender.
Example:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //some your code
    eventRender: function(calEvent, htmlElem, view) {
        switch(calEvent.type) {
            case 'public':
                htmlElem.addClass('public_event');
                break;
            case 'personal':
                htmlElem.addClass('personal_event');
                break;
        }
    }, 
    //some your code
});
```